# How "safe" is it to set up my email on IMAP without SSL?

Tags: tls, email

I have to set up my mail client to check my emails on iOs. However, for some reason, I am unable to use the SSL option (for mail server login) ... I want to know if it is "safe" for me to opt for the non-SSL login option?

Comment: without SSL your username and password are sent in the clear everytime you log in

Comment: Thanks Schroeder! I guess that answers the question :-) Scary!

Answer (score 3):

Accessing an IMAP server without TLS means that an attacker in the network

- can sniff your username and password. Since these are often also used to authenticate when sending mail an attacker can send mail in your name.
- can read and maybe even modify any mails your receive as an active man in the middle. For example an attacker might be able to replace some innocent attachment from a trusted person with an malicious attachment. The attacker might also delete mails or inject new mails, i.e. essentially the attacker is your mail server.

Note that TLS does not necessarily protect against all this. Many mail clients have the option to use TLS but accept any certificate. In this case such the man in the middle attacks are still possible since the attacker can present an arbitrary certificate instead of the certificate from the original IMAP server.
Also, TLS does not protect against an attacker which compromised the IMAP server itself.

Comment: Point 1 *might* not be correct -- if the server and client both support it, they might use an encrypted authentication method (e.g. CRAM-MD5) rather than sending a plaintext (or pain-equivalent) password. Maybe.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: you are correct in theory. In practice most IMAP servers don't offer CRAM-MD5 since the password needs to be stored for this in plaintext or in some "similar" (i.e. directly usable for authentication against the IMAP server) on the server which it is usually not.